# Grep every string inside specific X string

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want **every string *inside*** `$this->translate('')` or `$this->translate("")`, I've come up with

```
grep -oe "\$this\->translate(\(['\"].*['\"]\))" -r dir/path
```

but this is bringing results like

```
$this->translate('Something?').'\');">'.$this->translate('Something else')
```

Each `translate` should be shown in separate lines. I tried using `non-greedy/lazy` but didn't work out.

**Input samples**

```
$this->translate('Something?').'\');">'.$this->translate('Something else')
<span><?= $this->translate('random text');?></span>
```

**Expected output**

```
Something
Something else
random text
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: so in your case `grep -P -o '(?<=\$this->translate\(["'\''])[^)]*?(?=["'\'']\))'`